# Jscolor not showing properly

Tags: javascript, css, bootbox, jscolor

I am using `bootbox` and `jscolor`, however when I clicked the field of my `jscolor`, the `jscolor` pallete is behind of the `bootbox`. How can I bring it to front the `jscolor`?

Comment: change z-index property

Answer (score 6):

This is problem of z-index. jscolor has very low z-index which is obviously very bad. I had the same problem. I opened the jscolor.min.js file, search for zIndex and changed it from 1e3 to 1e6 and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

don't type z-index, because the console error says that it has trouble understanding '-', the plugin automatically changes classes to camelCase, so instead of z-index in the customization, try 'zIndex' worked for me!